# What are the use cases for inheriting the str class?

Tags: python

I'm currently learning OOP in Python and came across a book called "Mastering OOP by Steven F. Lott". In this book there is class which inherits from `str` and after excluding the inheritance the class seems to work the same way. Thus I was wondering what are the good use cases to inherit from `str`:

```
from enum import Enum

class Suit(str,Enum):
   Club = "♣"
   Diamond = "♦"
   Heart = "♥"
   Spade = "♠"

cards = [AceCard('A', Suit.Spade), Card('2',Suit.Spade), FaceCard('J',Suit.Spade),]

print([c.suit for c in cards])

[<Suit.Spade: '♠'>, <Suit.Spade: '♠'>, <Suit.Spade: '♠'>]
```

I also learnt that if one wants to inherit from type `str` and modify after. One should implement the `__new__` static method as in:

```
class Suit(str):
    def __new__(cls,*args,**kwargs):
        return str.__new__(cls,*args,**kwargs)
```

However again I'm not sure how one would make good use of this inheritance.

Comment: Basically none. This example isn’t a good idea – using the `value` property whenever the string form of the enum value is needed would be much cleaner.

Comment: Please give me good examples then.

Comment: Like I said, there aren’t any. :P

Comment: but what would be a good use case besides the example I provided of `str` ? really that there aren't any ? so why so people use it ?

Comment: Note also that `__new__` is not a static method.

Answer (score 3):

Probably it is always good to avoid it as it is non intuitive for others.
**TLDR; Think about Python Zen, if such class is a good idea or not.**

---

There is one wide spread usecases: `numpy.str_` which you have when you have numpy arrays with a max string length.
It combines string methods with some numpy methods, but it is hidden under the hood.
For low-level tasks it might be actually good to have more control over strings and attributes, but from a high level perspective should appear like normal strings.

---

High level use-cases probably are hackish or lazy to avoid work at other places, which would be more intuitive for others. But more work for you.

One use case you work with pretty long strings in lists, dicts, whatever.
Printing them will crowd your output.
Writing a `format_long_output` function takes a bit more time and you have to use it every time.
Why not have a string class that handles the formatting for you?

```py
class longstr(str):
   def __str__(self):
       return self[:5] + "..."

   def __repr__(self):
       # Overwrite accordingly
       return "'" + self + "'" # this is the default
```

Likewise assume you have specially formatted strings with some patterns and values you want to extract for easy access.
You could perform checks with them and format the output to your liking.

```py
class pattern(str):
   def __init__(self, input):
       r = re.match( "(some format)", input)
       if r is None:
           raise ValueError("Invalid Input string")
       self.value1 = r.groups(1)

   def __str__(self):
       return "Special Value:" + self.value1
```

Or you want some custom concatenating or math rules...

Dangerous if non proper classes meet `type(mystring) == str` statements.
Which probably are quite popular.

---

---

### Conclusion

I think in the end it boils down to:
Have cleaner less error prone code vs. have a complex str class

Such classes will be good if check statements are needed at multiple locations in the code and are hard to track down if forgotten. -> **Complex is better than complicated**

If you need to do such a check just once, twice at the start, do it manually with a normal str class. -> **Simple is better than complex**

---

### Python Zen

And think about some of the **Pyhton Zen** statements, which way will fullfill it more?

**Beautiful is better than ugly.**
Explicit is better than implicit.

**Simple is better than complex.**
**Complex is better than complicated.**

Readability counts.

**Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.

Although practicality beats purity.**

**There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.**

**If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.

If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.**

Answer (score 2):

There is one major use case for inheriting from `str` and builtin classes like it: backwards compatibility.

Suppose you are writing a library for managing dingbat widgets. These dingbat widgets have a status (let's say they can be `pending`, `accepted`, or `rejected`). You decide to model that status as a string. So you might have a status `Dingbat.get_status()` which returns one of `'pending'`, `'accepted'` or `'rejected'`. You also have methods for changing status or asking for all dingbats with a certain status and the like.

You release it, and it's a success, lots of people start using your library. They start to depend on these strings, and write code like `if my_dingbat.get_status() == 'accepted':`.

Then you decide to release a new version of your library, and you want to make use of `enum.Enum` for the status.

To prevent all the code of your users from breaking, the new status enum needs to inherit from `str`.

In my example, instead of explicitly inheriting from `str` and `enum.Enum`, it would make more sense to inherit only from [`enum.StrEnum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.StrEnum), which exists for making drop-in replacements for `str` values.

Answer (score 0):

> Thus I was wondering what are the good use cases to inherit from str:

- Members of `StrEnum` are strings, which means that you can use them
  almost anywhere that a regular string is expected.
- Because enums are glorified classes, you are free to put ordinary
  methods and properties into them. For example, you can define a
  property of a Mark member that will return the other member.

Snippet:

```
from __future__ import annotations
import enum


class Cards(enum.StrEnum):
    Club = "♣"
    Diamond = "♦"
    Heart = "♥"
    Spade = "♠"

    
    @property
    def other(self) -> Cards:
        return

    
print(Cards.Club)
print(Cards['Club'])
print(Cards("♣").other)
print(Cards("♠").name)
print(Cards.Club.value)
print(Cards.Club == 'Club')
print(isinstance(Cards.Club, str))

 
for music_genre in Cards:
    print(music_genre)
```

Output:

```
♣
♣
None
Spade
♣
False
True
♣
♦
♥
♠
```